# AppState module error when migrating to react native 0.57

Tags: react-native

After migrating my Android application from react-native **0.52** to **0.57** I get the following error message when I start it:

> Cannot use 'AppState' module when native 'RCTAppState' is not included
>   in the build. Either include it, or check 'AppState'.isAvailable
>   before calling any methods.

The issue is that this error is throw by react native code itself; the stack trace being basically:

```
> global code 
> metroRequire 
> guardedLoadModule 
> loadModuleImplementation 
> ... 
> connectToDevTools 
> isAppActive 
> AppState.get 
> throwMissingNativeModule
```

So I can't follow the recommendation *check 'AppState'.isAvailable before calling any method*.

I found the change in react native that throws this error: https://github.com/gaearon/react-native/commit/118e88393e389ff70e30ada10a69b72dd31d869a but I didn't find any related changes in [rn-diff](https://github.com/ncuillery/rn-diff) so I'm not sure about what to migrate.

My `MainApplication.java` has a `ReactPackage` that extends `MainReactPackage` that registers the `AppStateModule`, so for me the AppState module is here.

I tried:

- cleaning my Android Studio Project and rebuilding -> no change
- using react-native-git-upgrade to migrate -> tells me the migration worked but doesn't change any file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the issue; my native modules declaration looked like:

```
 modules.add(ModuleSpec.nativeModuleSpec(AppStateModule.class, new Provider<NativeModule>() {
    @Override
    public NativeModule get() {
      return new ContactsModule(context, MainApplication.this);
    }
  }));
  modules.add(ModuleSpec.nativeModuleSpec(AppStateModule.class, new Provider<NativeModule>() {
    @Override
    public NativeModule get() {
      return new SettingsModule(context, MainApplication.this);
    }
  }));
  modules.add(ModuleSpec.nativeModuleSpec(AppStateModule.class, new Provider<NativeModule>() {
    @Override
    public NativeModule get() {
      return new NativeUiModule(context, MainApplication.this);
    }
  }));
```

As you can see I was using `AppStateModule.class` as first argument to `.nativeModuleSpec` and it worked before, but this was probably wrong and in newer version of react native this is probably replacing the original AppState module. **I fixed it by using each time the relevant class**.

This way of declaring react native modules is also quite old, the latest documentation give a way simpler declaration I should also migrate that.